# SQL Server: SELECT from multiple lines if values exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to write a query that would select data from multiple lines depending if there is a newer value. This has been giving me headaches for a long time already. The table is structured this way:

```
UniqID ProblemID  DateTime   Status PersonID ResponsibleID ActionID Comment  Deadline    PartID
15589   15589    01/16 12:11   0       25         48          12      bla1   01/16 12:11  T9865
15592   15589    01/16 12:25   1       48         48          105     bla2   null         null
15601   15589    01/16 13:08   3       56         null        195     bla3   null         N2654
15641   15589    01/17 18:02   3       11         23          35      null   01/18 15:00  null
15705   15589    01/18 10:24   5       23         null        255     bla4   null         null
```

This is a mistake log and I need to perform several slightly different queries on this data.

- e.g. if person 48 was involved with this mistake (15589) as `PersonID` or as `ResponsibleID`.

This query would have to return

```
    ProblemID (first)DateTime (last)Status (first)Person (last)Responsible (last)action (first)Comment (last)deadline (last)PartID        
      15589      01/16 12:11       5            25            23                255         bla1        01/18 15:00      N2654
```

- e.g show all mistakes for the last 24hours
- e.g show all mistakes where `PartID` T9865 was involved

I have made several attempts at this query, but the best that came out was a query that selects all stuff from the last line or the first one. I am actually struggling to figure out how to select the (last)`ResponsibleID` if it is not contained in the last line. The same for other columns obviously. The only solution I can think of right now is a simple select that would return me all the rows and just filter that necessary data in a foreach loop with PHP. Because selecting different values in multiple lines is just beyond my skill :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I always prefer shortcut text description, like: I've `this`, I want to `that` but having `those` problem, thanks for your effort!

Comment: What do you mean? Is my explanation of the problem reasonably well formatted or the opposite of that?

Comment: Your explanation is good enough that you wanted to depict, but I just have told you my ways that I prefer, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I can think of is to repeat the conditions in subselects. I see no other way to get to the first/last column values that are `NOT NULL`.

#### SQL Statement

```
;WITH CurrentProblemID AS (
  SELECT  DISTINCT ProblemID
  FROM    Mistakes 
  WHERE   PersonID = 48 
          OR ResponsibleID = 48
)

SELECT  [ProblemID] = cpi.ProblemID
        , [(first) DateTime] = (SELECT MIN(DateTime) FROM Mistakes WHERE ProblemID = cpi.ProblemID AND DateTime IS NOT NULL)
        , [(last) Status] = (SELECT Status FROM Mistakes WHERE DateTime = (SELECT MAX(DateTime) FROM Mistakes WHERE ProblemID = cpi.ProblemID AND Status IS NOT NULL))
        , [(first) Person] = (SELECT PersonID FROM Mistakes WHERE DateTime = (SELECT MIN(DateTime) FROM Mistakes WHERE ProblemID = cpi.ProblemID AND PersonID IS NOT NULL))
        , [(last) Responsible] = (SELECT ResponsibleID FROM Mistakes WHERE DateTime = (SELECT MAX(DateTime) FROM Mistakes WHERE ProblemID = cpi.ProblemID AND ResponsibleID IS NOT NULL))
        , [(last) Action] = (SELECT ActionID FROM Mistakes WHERE DateTime = (SELECT MAX(DateTime) FROM Mistakes WHERE ProblemID = cpi.ProblemID AND ActionID IS NOT NULL))
        , [(first) Comment] = (SELECT Comment FROM Mistakes WHERE DateTime = (SELECT MIN(DateTime) FROM Mistakes WHERE ProblemID = cpi.ProblemID AND Comment IS NOT NULL))
        , [(last) Deadline] = (SELECT Deadline FROM Mistakes WHERE DateTime = (SELECT MAX(DateTime) FROM Mistakes WHERE ProblemID = cpi.ProblemID AND Deadline IS NOT NULL))
        , [(last) PartID] = (SELECT PartID FROM Mistakes WHERE DateTime = (SELECT MAX(DateTime) FROM Mistakes WHERE ProblemID = cpi.ProblemID AND PartID IS NOT NULL))
FROM    CurrentProblemID cpi
```

#### Test script

```
;WITH Mistakes AS (
  SELECT  *
  FROM    ( 
            VALUES
              (15589, 15589, '01/16 12:11', 0, 25, 48, 12, 'bla1', '01/16 12:11', 'T9865')
              , (15592, 15589, '01/16 12:25', 1, 48, 48, 105, 'bla2', null, null)
              , (15601, 15589, '01/16 13:08', 3, 56, null, 195, 'bla3', null, 'N2654')
              , (15641, 15589, '01/17 18:02', 3, 11, 23, 35, null, '01/18 15:00', null)
              , (15705, 15589, '01/18 10:24', 5, 23, null, 255, 'bla4', null, null)
          ) AS v (UniqID, ProblemID, DateTime, Status, PersonID, ResponsibleID, ActionID, Comment, Deadline, PartID)
)          
, CurrentProblemID AS (
  SELECT  DISTINCT ProblemID
  FROM    Mistakes 
  WHERE   PersonID = 48 
          OR ResponsibleID = 48
)

SELECT  [ProblemID] = cpi.ProblemID
        , [(first) DateTime] = (SELECT MIN(DateTime) FROM Mistakes WHERE ProblemID = cpi.ProblemID AND DateTime IS NOT NULL)
        , [(last) Status] = (SELECT Status FROM Mistakes WHERE DateTime = (SELECT MAX(DateTime) FROM Mistakes WHERE ProblemID = cpi.ProblemID AND Status IS NOT NULL))
        , [(first) Person] = (SELECT PersonID FROM Mistakes WHERE DateTime = (SELECT MIN(DateTime) FROM Mistakes WHERE ProblemID = cpi.ProblemID AND PersonID IS NOT NULL))
        , [(last) Responsible] = (SELECT ResponsibleID FROM Mistakes WHERE DateTime = (SELECT MAX(DateTime) FROM Mistakes WHERE ProblemID = cpi.ProblemID AND ResponsibleID IS NOT NULL))
        , [(last) Action] = (SELECT ActionID FROM Mistakes WHERE DateTime = (SELECT MAX(DateTime) FROM Mistakes WHERE ProblemID = cpi.ProblemID AND ActionID IS NOT NULL))
        , [(first) Comment] = (SELECT Comment FROM Mistakes WHERE DateTime = (SELECT MIN(DateTime) FROM Mistakes WHERE ProblemID = cpi.ProblemID AND Comment IS NOT NULL))
        , [(last) Deadline] = (SELECT Deadline FROM Mistakes WHERE DateTime = (SELECT MAX(DateTime) FROM Mistakes WHERE ProblemID = cpi.ProblemID AND Deadline IS NOT NULL))
        , [(last) PartID] = (SELECT PartID FROM Mistakes WHERE DateTime = (SELECT MAX(DateTime) FROM Mistakes WHERE ProblemID = cpi.ProblemID AND PartID IS NOT NULL))
FROM    CurrentProblemID cpi
```

Comment: I don't think first and last mean min or max functions, just first non null entry and last non null entry

Comment: @Adrian lftode - I know, it's not immediatly vissible due to scrolling but that is taken care of in each subselect at the end. Reformatting to make this more visible would be one option but it would become even more less readable <g>.

Comment: Yeah that is true. I want only where the data is not null.

Comment: @Lieven not yet, have to get to work first :) I will let you know what happened in approx 1hour.

Comment: @GEMI - I have this nagging feeling it could be **simplified** but I'm pretty confident this **is** what you need :).

Comment: @Lieven It looks promising as far as I can tell. But as you point out it probably could be simplified, right now it is rather brute-force'ish if there is such a word :) I will also let you know about the execution time.

Comment: Given the complexity of this, it may be cheaper in terms of processing just to chuck the raw records to the client application and let it have the job of working out what to display.

Comment: @Lieven Yeah the query works, but takes about 0.02 sec to execute :)

Comment: @GEMI - Probably this can be optimized by adding appropriate indexes but you should take into account that adding indexes improves searching but slows down updates/deletes/inserts. Getting it all to the client and let the client work it out is another alternative but make sure to test the performance on large resultsets. It might prove difficult to outperform SQL Server

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I will look into moving the calculations to my app instead of SQL.

Answer (score 1):

TBH this probably isn't a problem for SQL to solve, but a problem for the business logic code. So whilst you will undoubtedly come up with a query that will do what you need, it may be simpler to just return all records to the client application, and have the client code deal with the problem of determining the pertinent records to display.

Comment: That is what I am thinking at the moment. Although I though that someone has already solved this problem as there are many apps that track the history and have data logs like this.

Comment: It comes down to one of performance: I've been burnt by people pushing logic into the database layer to keep the business code simple (in some cases the business logic ends up being nothing more than a proxy to the database). The result is that the database server has a large amount of load whilst the application servers tick along at nearly idle. Cleverer coding would have meant a less beefy database server without losing any performance because the app servers would be doing something useful. This is one of those cases :-)

Comment: How would you suggest improving current table structure, if I would move all calculations to app instead of SQL server?

Comment: Keep the table the same, just parse the results in application code (so you effectively do SELECT * FROM [...] WHERE ProblemID = ...). How many rows can each problem have (typically). If it's a fairly small number (say, < 200), then this is a good approach. Lots of rows (1000, 2000 or more), then it's probably better to get SQL to do some heavy lifting (purely due to the amount of data you're sending over the wire from the database). Anything in the middle - well you need to make a judgement call knowing (a) how heavily it's hit (b) your environment architecture (hardware and software).

Answer (score 0):

### Following code might give you solution

```
SELECT  ABC.PROBLEMID,
        ABC.DATETIME,--(first)DateTime 
        ABC.STATUS,--(last)Status
        ABC.PERSON,-- (first)Person
        ABC.RESPONSIBLE,-- (last)Responsible
        ABC.ACTION,-- (last)action
        ABC.COMMENT,-- (first)Comment
        ABC.DEADLINE,-- (last)deadline
        ABC.PARTID -- (last)PartID
(
SELECT TOP 1 PROBLEMID,DATETIME,PERSON,COMMENT 
FROM YOURTABLE
ORDER BY DATETIME ASC
OR
SELECT TOP 1 STATUS,RESPONSIBLE,ACTION,DEADLINE,PARTID
FROM YOURTABLE
ORDER BY DATETIME DESC
) ABC
WHERE ABC.PROBLEMID IN (SELECT  DISTINCT ProblemID
                        FROM    Mistakes 
                        WHERE   PersonID = 48 
                           OR   ResponsibleID = 48)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this query does not determine if person (48) was involved in this mistake. Because right now it only looks for last responsible and first person, but what if person 48 is not the first and not the last? What if he is somewhere in the middle?